# c++ multidimensional array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

In book i found example

```
static int categoryTable[ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ] = {
    //!b!c  !bc  b!c  bc
      0,    3,   2,   2, //!a
      1,    2,   1,   1  // a
};

category = categoryTable[ a ][ b ][ c ]
```

There is mistake, right?

Right variant is

```
static int categoryTable[ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ] = {
    //!b!c   !bc    b!c  bc
     {{0,    3},   {2,   2}}, //!a
     {{1,    2},   {1,   1}}  // a
};
```

Or original is right and I don't understand something?

Comment: IIRC, both will compile. The compiler stores them the same way in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Beefster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5079779/beefster) said both ways are correct and will compile.

Multidimensional arrays are just plain single-dimension arrays for the compiler but for programmers they are a nice sugar syntax for complex pointer arithmetics.

Because the multidimensional array is in the reality a single dimension array with syntax improvements then there's no point to disallow initialization with single initializer list.

Expression

```
a[0][2][3] = x;
```

is equivalent of `*(a+(0*DIM_1+2)*DIM_2+3) = x;`

What's not a part of your question but also interesting that because it's just pointer arithmetics you could write:

```
3[a]
```

That is equivalent of array subscription:

```
a[3]
```

So as a fun fact - you can do similar stuff with multidimensional arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int categoryTable[ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ] = {
    //!b!c  !bc  b!c  bc
      0,    3,   2,   2, //!a
      1,    2,   1,   1  // a
};

int main() {
  // This two printf's are equivalent
  printf("%d\n", 0[0[categoryTable][1]]);
  printf("%d\n", categoryTable[0][1][0]);
  return 0;
}
```

This is rather an ugly never-do-it thing, but funny anyway.

So you can think about subscription as some kind of mathematical expression to access single plain array - nothing special really.

Comment: "*Multidimensional arrays are just plain single-dimension arrays [with] nice sugar syntax*" - so, `static int categoryTable[ 2 ][ 2 ][ 2 ] = {...};` is essentially `static int categoryTable[8] = {...};`, which is why a single set of braces can be used to initialize its elements.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. You can use any one of them.